# How I can get all node from XSD?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd

How I can get all nodes from XSD in C# like this:

I have this example:

[image]

Data I need:

```
employees/
employees/employee/
employees/employee/name
employees/employee/adress
employees/employee/adress/postalcode/
```

I need all possible node from XSD. I used XmlSchema element.Attribute but I can get parent nodes, any ideas?

```
My Code:
var xs = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
var doc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
string node = string.Empty;
foreach (var element in doc.Descendants(xs + "element"))
  {
     string name = element.Attribute("name").Value+"/";
     node += name;
  }
```

Comment: Please post the Schema as text, rather than an image.  This makes it easier for someone else to reproduce.

Comment: The schema is recursive and not easy to get hierarchical structure.  Better to download from msdn xsd.exe.  Then use the tool to create classes from schema and place into your project.  Very simple to parse actual xml data using the xml serialize class.

Comment: A lot depends on how general you want to make your code. Does it have to work with any schema, or just with a schema that is very similar to your example? It becomes much more complicated if the schema consists of multiple schema documents, or if it uses features such as model groups, types derived by extension, or substitution groups. (One example does not make a specification...)